# BigTable query, GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL not working when using __KEY__

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In my app, I have Photos that have associated comments. When I retrieve the target list of photos I save the high / low keys of the Photos to contain the list of comments I query for.

The problem I am having is that the Query will not return the comments for the last photo.

It's almost as if the GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL is operating as GREATER_THAN.

I can get the query to work by deconstructing the high key and adding 1 to its id.

Is this a bug or am I expecting the wrong thing ?

SDK Release 1.6.1
SDK Timestamp: Mon Dec 12 14:53:13 PST 2011
API versions: [1.0]

Here is my code, below that is the work around code.

```
Query q = new Query (EntityNames.EventPhotoComment.name());

q.addFilter(
 Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY,
 Query.FilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
 highPhotoKey);

q.addFilter(
 Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY,
 Query.FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
 lowPhotoKey);

q.addSort(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY,
 Query.SortDirection.ASCENDING);

PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);
Iterator<Entity> dbDataIterator = pq.asIterator();
```

Work around code.

```
  long id = highPhotoKey.getId();
  Key parent = highPhotoKey.getParent();
  highPhotoKey = KeyFactory.createKey(parent,EntityNames.EventPhoto.name(), id+1);
```

Comment: This is not a question about Bigtable but rather a question about the Datastore API for Google App Engine.